# how to write a JPA method to fetch entity queries by two level nested entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have the entities such as

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Person implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int credit;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Bank implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String name;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int duration;

    @Singular
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<PersonCredit> personCredits = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PersonCredit implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Person person;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private int annualRate;

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Billing implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Person person;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private LocalDate lastPaymentDate;

    @Basic(optional = false)
    private long amount;
}
```

Now I need to find all Banks who offer load for the person for a particular Bill.

How do I write a JPA repository method in BankRepository?

which fetches the Bank offering the load based upon the Person
when the relationship defined is `Bank -> PersonCredit -> Person`

A method to find all banks offering the load, find a person

Since it is not a direct relationship, I don't know how to do it

Comment: can you explain what `Banks who offer load for the person for a particular Bill` means or explain it in terms of how your query/entities should interact

Comment: @BIBOOnation : Bank just offers the person loan to pay bill according to the credit , also even without the functionality , how can I write a Bank repository method to find all Banks findByPerson

Comment: Not sure how `Billing` fits into this but you could start with `Bank` and join `PersonCredit` and `Person` from there. Finally add a where-clause to filter as needed. Of course having back references might make the queries easier to read and help the DB's query planner optimize. - I'm pretty sure though, that Spring cannot generate that method for you just from the name so you might need to add your own query or maybe even full implementation of that method.